# Json array display through jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I am new with JSON arrays manipulation. I have a php file that returns a json_encode() result.

It is returning this result:

```
{
    "result": {
        "2015-08-24": {
            "qty": 13,
            "qty_items": 85,
            "subtotal": "Dh11170.09",
            "discount_total": "Dh80.00",
            "adjustment_amt": "Dh-8.00",
            "payments_amt": "Dh3673.75",
            "balance": "Dh7837.84",
            "average": "Dh282.60",
            "details": [
                {
                    "time": "12:47",
                    "sales_id": "100001",
                    "status": "Closed",
                    "client_id": "3275",
                    "client_name": "Nathan Dudley",
                    "subtotal": "Dh300.00",
                    "discount_total": "Dh0.00",
                    "adjust_amt": "Dh0.00",
                    "payments_amt": "Dh300.00",
                    "balance": "Dh0.00",
                    "employee_id": "1914",
                    "employee_name": "Sofia Ferrai"
                },
                {
                    "time": "12:50",
                    "sales_id": "100002",
                    "status": "Open",
                    "client_id": "3599",
                    "client_name": "Scott Cunningham",
                    "subtotal": "Dh400.00",
                    "discount_total": "Dh80.00",
                    "adjust_amt": "Dh32.00",
                    "payments_amt": "Dh0.00",
                    "balance": "Dh288.00",
                    "employee_id": "1914",
                    "employee_name": "Sofia Ferrai"
                },
                {
                    "time": "13:08",
                    "sales_id": "100003",
                    "status": "Open",
                    "client_id": "1",
                    "client_name": "No Client",
                    "subtotal": "Dh2080.00",
                    "discount_total": "Dh0.00",
                    "adjust_amt": "Dh-646.40",
                    "payments_amt": "Dh0.00",
                    "balance": "Dh2726.40",
                    "employee_id": "2060",
                    "employee_name": "Irene Pi"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to go through it and display it in a table via jquery. Please help. Thanks

Comment: What do you need help with?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am getting this result on success of an jquery ajax call, just need to display in html table.

Comment: What *exactly* do you need help with?  What part of this are you stuck on?  What do you not know how to do?  What do you want from us?

Comment: I need to access the elements. need the correct loop syntax. Please check this: http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/0a6a98. 

First need to show just dates

Comment: Have you tried anything to do this yourself?  Do you know how to use a loop?  Do you know how to insert/append elements?  What *exactly* do you need from us?  We're not just going to give you the code.  We're here to assist, not do it for you.

Comment: yes I tried a lot but it displays nothing.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?  That will help us help you.

Comment: success: function(results) {
      if(results.response_code == '1'){
        // no results found
      }
      else{
       for(var i=0;i<(results).length;i++)
       {
        strDetails = strDetails + "<tr class=\"whitebgcolor\">";
        strDetails = strDetails + "<td class=\"black3_bo\" width=\"25%\" align=\"left\" colspan=\"9\">"+results[i]+"</td>";
        strDetails = strDetails + "</tr>";
        
       }    jQuery("#spItemDetails").html(strDetails);
      }  }

Comment: I checked the result by doing this:

Comment: alert(JSON.stringify(results));

Comment: here you go @Iram. try this http://jsfiddle.net/sEwM6/2855/ let me know if it helps

Comment: sure @gibberish will do that. give me a few minutes

Comment: @gibberish I've posted my answer and Iram you can check that too. I've kept it as simple as possible. hope it solves your problem.

Comment: @Iram Please make sure you select Sushil's answer as the correct answer (click checkmark) *and (optionally) upvote it also (up arrow)* to close this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your `JSON` is a little tricky since you have dynamic `dates` inside the results. had a tough time figuring that out but was able to finally get through it.

so to solve your problem lets assume you have this table in your html

```
<table id="personDataTable" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Sales Id</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Client Id</th>
        <th>Client Name</th>
        <th>Subtotal</th>
        <th>Discount Total</th>
        <th>Adjust Amount</th>
        <th>Payments Amount</th>
        <th>Balance</th>
        <th>Employee Id</th>
        <th>Employee Name</th>
    </tr>

</table>
```

there are two important methods that I've made in jquery. these 2 will create the table.

```
function drawTable(data) {

    var propName;
    for (propName in data.result) {
        var details = data.result[propName].details;
        console.log(data.result[propName].details);
        for (var i = 0; i < details.length; i++) {
            drawRow(details[i]);
        }
    }


    console.log(data.result.children);

}

function drawRow(rowData) {
    var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#personDataTable").append(row); //this will append tr element to table... keep its reference for a while since we will add cels into it
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.time + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.sales_id + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.status + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.client_id + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.client_name + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.subtotal + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.discount_total + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.adjust_amt + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.payments_amt + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.balance + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.employee_id + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.employee_name + "</td>"));

}
```

now all you need is to call the `drawTable` method inside your success event and you will have your table ready.

Have a look at this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sEwM6/2855/)**. hope this helps.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88954/discussion-on-answer-by-sushil-json-array-display-through-jquery).